# Difference between meta tags Content-Language and language

Tags: language, meta-tags

What's the difference between these two meta-tags

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="de, en"/>
<meta name="language" content="de, en">
```

Are they both needed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Content-language` is [going away soon](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/meta.http-equiv.content-language.html) (note the big red "obsolete"), and I'm not sure `language` was ever official.  The W3C recommends this instead:

```
<html lang="en">
```

The `lang` attribute works with most tags (except `<script />`, `<br />`, `<frame />`, etc), so you can mix, match, and cascade:

```
<p>This is English, since the html tag covers it.</p>
<p lang="ja">しかし、これではない</p>
<p>And back to English.</p>
```

It's been around since HTML 4 so it's safe. Since it's just a semantic descriptor, browsers don't "fully" support it (they only need to know the character set).  Google & friends understand it though, and that probably matters more.